# Solve conditional term with mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, conditional

Solve mathematical conditional expressions with Mathematica, e.g if $x+y=3$ and $xy=-1$ , what is result $\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 8):

The lazy way to do this is to evaluate

```
Solve[{z == (x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2), x + y == 3, x y == -1}, z, {x, y}]
   {{z -> 36/11}}
```

---

The clever way to do this is to recognize that your rational function is symmetric, and is thus representable in terms of the symmetric polynomials:

```
Table[SymmetricPolynomial[k, {x, y}], {k, 2}]
   {x + y, x y}
```

which means you can leverage `SymmetricReduction[]`:

```
expr = (x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2)
Total[SymmetricReduction[Numerator[expr], {x, y}, {s1, s2}]]/
Total[SymmetricReduction[Denominator[expr], {x, y}, {s1, s2}]]
   (s1^3 - 3 s1 s2)/(s1^2 - 2 s2)
```

after which you can plug the specified values in:

```
% /. Thread[{s1, s2} -> {3, -1}]
   36/11
```

(The [Newton-Girard formulae](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-GirardFormulas.html) are relevant here.)

---

The even more clever way is to recall [Vieta's formulae](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html)

```
Collect[(t - x) (t - y), t, Simplify]
   t^2 + t (-x - y) + x y
```

and recall that power sums of the form `x^k + y^k` satisfy a linear difference equation, with the recurrence coefficients being given by the symmetric expressions embodied in Vieta's formulae. Thus,

```
#2/#1 & @@ LinearRecurrence[{3 (* x + y *), 1 (* -x y *)},
                           {2 (* x^0 + y^0 *), 3 (* x^1 + y^1 *)},
                           {2, 3} + 1]
   36/11
```

Answer (score 6):

A simpler way is as follows.

```
Simplify[(x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2), {x + y == 3, x y == -1}]
```

> `36/11`

Answer (score 4):

We consider that `a[n]=x^n + y^n`. To deduce the recurrence relation we compare with `x^(n + 2) + y^(n + 2)` and `x^(n + 1) + y^(n + 1)` up to a factor `x+y`.

```
Simplify[x^(n + 2) + y^(n + 2) - (x + y) (x^(n + 1) + y^(n + 1)), 
 n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `-x y (x^n + y^n)`.

It means that

```
Simplify[
 x^(n + 2) + y^(n + 2) == (x + y) (x^(n + 1) + y^(n + 1)) - 
   x y (x^n + y^n), n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `True`.

When `x+y==3,x y==-1`, the recurrence relation `a[n + 2] == 3 a[n + 1] + a[n]`, and `a[1] == 3, a[0] == 2` hold.

```
RSolve[{a[n + 2] == 3 a[n + 1] + a[n], a[1] == 3, a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]
```

[image]

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 2] == 3 a[n + 1] + a[n], a[1] == 3, 
  a[0] == 2}, a, {n, 2, 3}]
```

> `{11, 36}`.

`a[3]/a[2]==36/11`.

Comment: Since you bring up `RSolve[]`, you could also note that `RSolveValue[]` can give the ratio at once: `RSolveValue[{a[n + 2] == 3 a[n + 1] + a[n], a[1] == 3, a[0] == 2}, a[3]/a[2], n] // Simplify`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for provide this skill.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to first solve for $x,y$ using `Solve` command, and then replace all the solutions into the expression.

Something like

```
ClearAll[x,y]
expr=(x^3+y^3)/(x^2+y^2);
eq1=x+y==3;
eq2=x*y==-1;
sol=Solve[{eq1,eq2},{x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr/.sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the same numerically

```
N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]